# azure cloud service worker role vm not mounting local drive

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have been trying to mount my local resources(drive C:) and I am not winning, is there a way to transfer resources from my local to a VM? When I try to remote desktop to it, it keeps connecting for a very long time. I have selected the "drives" on the "more" section,this is the screenshot[image]

When I use my RDP it does not give me the option to mount my drives
[image: rdp downloaded from azure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** With Azure Cloud Services, if you connect from **Portal** or **RDP tool**, which allows the remote computer to access the following resources on my computer.

**Clipboard**

**Printers**

**To access Local drives in Azure Cloud Services, you may follow these steps:**

Open **Visual Studio** => Navigate to **your Cloud Services Instance** => Right Click => **Connect using Remote Desktop**

[image]

Before connecting, go to **Local Resources** => **More** => **Add all**

[image]

Check the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have RDP your Classic VM with the right **Public port** of Remote Desktop.

If not, Go to The ednpoint of your VM and find the Remote Desktop Public port.

Then run RDP, put your `VM's dns name` and `:<your public RDP port>`.

Example:

```
wayneclassic.cloudapp.net:57828
```

Also, you need to select the "drives" on the "more" section.Then just connect your VM.

Here is result:
[image]

Comment: I hope you have tried on Azure Virtual Machine. Which works well with VMs not Cloud Services.

Comment: Hi,@PRADEEPCHEEKATLA .Thank you for reminder. I updated the answer.